# wp jobmanager : Edit company field

Tags: wordpress, hook

I am trying to hook wp job manager submit form fields.

The company tagline hook not work.
This is my code in functions.php

```
add_filter( 'submit_job_form_fields', 'custom_submit_job_form_fields' );
function custom_submit_job_form_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['job']['job_tags']['required'] = true;
    //$fields['job']['job_type']['default'] = 'CDD';
    $fields['job']['job_type']['type'] = 'term-multiselect';
    $fields['job']['job_type']['required'] = false;
    $fields['company']['company_tagline']['maxlength'] = 200;

    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: You're better off contacting the plugin developer.

Comment: ok thanks , i will do that